# Augmented reality based android app for supermarket users

Tags: android, augmented-reality, indoor-positioning-system

I m an 4th undergraduate student and I have to make a demo on Augmented Reality in Android for my final year project at the university. This is for a supermarket.
 when user passes a specific shelf in the supermarket user wanted to be notified by the app if any promotions available for the items in that shelf.e.g like a message pop up with a pointing arrow to the shelf (assuming only one category of items available in one shelf)

I want to know is it possible to do by capturing an images of shelves and save it in the database and identify the images when user passes through and pop up message to the screen if any promotions available? or any other easy ways available to do this?

if so could you please give me what are the android sdk tools available for this purpose and and guide me with some references and examples which i should refer

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complex problem. You can approach it like below:

- Start with QR code recognition, this is now supported in the Google Vision API for Android devices. QR codes are available on most objects these days.
- Instead of storing the objects (which are loosely defined), see if you can store the logo's of the companies and the product name styling for comparison. You can then use OpenCV's numerous tools for this purpose. OpenCV is available on Android.
- Making it robust to take care of all conditions, is still an area of research, but look at what Amazon has done with Amazon Flow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable information. but still i need a small clarification,could i know if we going to recognize images by its logos and names by openCV,what is the point of recognising QR codes? @prabindh

Comment: Upto you. I mentioned the different phases that you could design this solution - 1st phase, only QR, 2nd phase Logo+Letters, 3rd phase More robust algorithms

Comment: Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answer if it answered your question.